# ROS Answers SE migration: uninstall ROS

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to know how to uninstall ROS on ubuntu

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28587/uninstall-ros/) by [monsterkappa](https://answers.ros.org/users/1863/monsterkappa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 97 on 2012-02-26

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-02-27**:
This is a duplicate of http://answers.ros.org/question/28589/uninstall-ros, please do not ask the same question twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

sudo apt-get remove ros-* if you installed from debian packages.

---

Originally posted by [Victor Lopez](https://answers.ros.org/users/395/victor-lopez/) with karma: 651 on 2012-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4